# Extracting StatusCode from TWebBrowser OnNavigateError in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm trying to get the HTTP response code in an OnNavigateError event of a TWebBrowser. The StatusCode passed to me is always -2146697211 when it should be 404. What am I missing? I'm using Delphi 10.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `TWebBrowser` uses Microsoft's Internet Explorer, so [information about the `NavigateError` event can be found online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb268221(v=vs.85)).
- The explanation of the `StatusCode` parameter [links to "NavigateError Event Status Codes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb268233(v=vs.85)) - there you see your typical 3-digit HTTP status codes, but also additional ones. Your **decimal** value of `-2146697211` is `$800C0005` in **hexadecimal** - both match the `INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND` constant, which again [links to another page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775145(v=vs.85)):
- It means "The server or proxy was not found."

Why is this a separate error code and not a HTTP one? Because it happens before HTTP is performed: looking up the IP address to a hostname has failed - nobody knows which IP address the hostname you tried to browse to has. That's what the [Domain Name System (DNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) is for. Not being able to get in contact with a server is a different thing than being able and getting a response. `HTTP 404` is a reponse. But since you don't even got a response, hence you cannot get a HTTP status code.

---

Long story short: **host not found** (instead of "HTTP 404" = *host found, but not the page you're looking for*). Try it with an address/a hostname that can be actually resolved.